# soup.find_all returning empty list

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am very new to python and I am trying to search for the specified postcode and print the corresponding city, however I have been unable to do so.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import html.parser

# I am using Chrome as default browser

url = ("http://google.co.uk/search?=sk71nd")
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
```

'''I thought the class below would return the following cities:
    Cities: Greater Manchester, Bramhall, Metropolitan Borough of Stockport, but instead I just get an empty list'''

```
print(soup.find_all("div", {'class': "zloOqf PZPZlf kno-fb-ctx"}))
```

Is it possible to search for the postcode provided and print the resulting cities? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import html.parser
import re

# I am using Chrome as default browser
data = []
data2 = []
url = ("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postcode_districts_in_the_United_Kingdom")
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
#print(soup.prettify())
table = soup.find("table", {"class": "toc"})
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])

print(data[1])

table = soup.find("table", {"class": "wikitable sortable"})
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data2.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])

print(data2)
```

> data1 - stores postal codes data2 - [Postcode area, Postcode
>   districts, Post Town, Former postal county]